# Pan Gesture Recognizer in Spritekit to move object

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, draggable, swift2, uipangesturerecognizer

I am trying to make a game in `spritkit` and cant figure out how i can drag the ball left and right across the screen just like a pan gesture recognizer.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene,SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

  var ball = SKShapeNode()
  let slidePlayer = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

  override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {   
    ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 15)
    ball.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, 500)
    ball.fillColor = SKColor.purpleColor()
    self.addChild(ball)

    slidePlayer.addTarget(ball, action: "slide")
    self.view?.addGestureRecognizer(slidePlayer)
  }

  func slide(){
    print("slide")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example code for playButton which I drag left and right across the screen.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let playButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "play_unpresed")
    var fingureIsOnNinja = false
    let playCategoryName = "play"

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        addPlayButton()
    }

    func addPlayButton(){

        playButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        playButton.xScale = 0.2
        playButton.yScale = 0.2
        playButton.name = playCategoryName  //give it a category name
        self.addChild(playButton)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>){
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.playButton {

                fingureIsOnNinja = true  //make this true so it will only move when you touch it.

            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        if fingureIsOnNinja {

            if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {

                let touchLoc = touch.locationInNode(self)
                let prevTouchLoc = touch.previousLocationInNode(self)
                let ninja = self.childNodeWithName(playCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode
                var newYPos = playButton.position.y + (touchLoc.y - prevTouchLoc.y)
                var newXPos = playButton.position.x + (touchLoc.x - prevTouchLoc.x)

                newYPos = max(newYPos, playButton.size.height / 2)
                newYPos = min(newYPos, self.size.height - playButton.size.height / 2)

                newXPos = max(newXPos, playButton.size.width / 2)
                newXPos = min(newXPos, self.size.width - playButton.size.width / 2)

                playButton.position = CGPointMake(newXPos, newYPos)  //set new X and Y for your sprite.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will help.

And you can follow [THIS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/96822/sprite-kit-tutorial-drag-drop-sprites) basic tutorial for touches in `SpriteKit`.

Comment: in the touches moved, im getting an error for " if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {" i think its because i may be using a leter version of swift, is there an updated version of this if statement

Comment: Just google it and you will find solution for it..:)

Comment: i cant find the swift 2 version of this line on google. The error im getting is NSSet does not have a member named "first"